# PSR-4 autoloading class after structure changes

Tags: php, class, autoload, psr-4

I think that it isn't a big problem. Probably I need a small change in my code. In my project I've the `src/` directory which contains `File.php` and `NoFileException.php` files.

`src/File.php`:

```
<?php

namespace myns;
use myns\NoFileException;

class File
{
 ...
}
```

`src/NoFileException.php`:

```
<?php

namespace myns;

class NoFileException extends \Exception
{
 ...
}
```

`composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "myns\\": "src/"
    }
 }
```

And everything works correctly. Now I would like to move the `NoFileException.php` at the `src/Exception/` directory. Thus I changed `src/File.php`:

```
<?php

namespace myns;
use myns\Exception\NoFileException;

class File
{
 ...
}
```

and `src/Exception/NoFileException.php`:

```
<?php

namespace myns\Exception; // doesn't work
//namespace myns;         // also does't work

class NoFileException extends \Exception
{
 ...
}
```

And I receive a statement that *class NoFileException not found*. I also added to `composer.json` a new mapping and tried different combinations of namespaces (I did `dump-autoload`). There is no reason to present all my attempts. How to solve this problem?

**EDIT**

The full message error, when namespace in the `src/Exception/NoFileException.php` is `myns`, looks like:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'myns\Exception\NoFileException' not found in /home/project/src/File.php:21
Stack trace: #0 /home/project/src/File.php(15):
myns\File->readable('r') #1 /home/project/index.php(20): 
myns\File->__construct('files/filename...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/project/src/File.php on line 21
```

When namespace is `myns\Exception` the error message is the same but without `Class` word at the beginning.

Comment: try to remove `composer.lock` and then run `composer install`.
Or just try `composer update`.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the options doesn't work. Still the same error.

Comment: please post full error text as it appears

Comment: `NoFileException` <> `FileException`

Comment: You may also want to run a composer dump-autoload

Comment: Ekhm, my fault, sorry for that. I've corrected the post. I has only two classes `File` and `NoFileException`. Of course the files have the same names. To be sure I've checked once again and the error has appeared again. I've also called a _composer dump-autoload_. As I mentioned above when both files are located at the `src/` directory the issue doesn't appear.

Comment: I found the solution. To catch the exception `myns\Exception\NoFileException` I also need to change `catch (myns\NoFileException $err)` to `catch (myns\Exception\NoFileException)`. This caused my problem. Class `NoFileException` was loaded properly.